# Custom Figure Citation Linking Text

Tags: cross-referencing

Below is my Coding

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

To test whether Figure \ref{fig1} a suspicious URL is vulnerable, we utilize the URL to download a representative Figure \ref{fig2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 1\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 2\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

what i need to achieve is explained below,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

To test whether \ref{fig1}{Figure 1} a suspicious URL is vulnerable, we utilize the URL to download a representative \ref{fig2}{Figure 2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 1\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 2\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In figure citation, I want my custom text to be displayed \ref{fig1}{Figure 1} and i want to use the \ref{fig1} for just linking purpose,

Thanks in Advance, please guide,

Comment: The [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package provides the `\cref` command that also includes the type of the label referred to. A more manual solution is explained in [Cross-Reference with custom text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70143/35864).

Comment: Another possibilty might be `\autoref`, which is defined by the already loaded package `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1):

As @moewe suggested i have found a solution, thanks to him as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

To test whether \hyperref[fig1]{Figure 1} a suspicious URL is vulnerable, we utilize the URL to download a representative \hyperref[fig2]{Figure 2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 1\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure 2\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```