# How to cross-reference text with a custom label/reference text?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, naming

How can we give a name to a label so that when we do the cross-reference, instead of displaying the number of the section, we have the name of the label?

For example,

```
\underline{homogeneity in preferences(HP)\phantomsection\label{hyp3}}
```

When I use `\ref{hyp3}` I would like the shown reference text to be `HP` and not e.g. `5.1` that is the number of the section.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70153/105976

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please provide a full minimal example so we can see what you are doing? Why are you making headlines marked by underline? Nobody does that anymore. LaTeX has several options when we are dealing with say `\section` then we can get the title associated with a `\label`, see for example the `nameref` package (it is build into the `memoir` class under the name `\titleref`)

Comment: You can also look at the packages `showkeys` or `showlabels`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Taking the excellent answer by egreg ([Labeling a text and referencing it later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/labeling-a-text-and-referencing-it-later)) and modifying it to take an additional optional argument I could come up with the solution below. It creates a new command `\labeltext` that can be referenced to. It takes two parameters and one optional parameter:

```
\labeltext[optional short ref]{the labeled text}{label name}
```

If you want to, you can set the markup or highlighting of the label and (optionally) the reference, too. I set it to `\emph` rather than `\underline` as underlining looks bad to me and is considered bad practice.

[image: result]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{underlin}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labeltext}[3][]{%
    \@bsphack%
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname% in case hyperref is used
    \def\tst{#1}%
    \def\labelmarkup{\emph}% How to markup the label itself
    %\def\refmarkup{\labelmarkup}% How to markup the reference
    \def\refmarkup{}%
    \ifx\tst\empty\def\@currentlabel{\refmarkup{#2}}{\label{#3}}%
    \else\def\@currentlabel{\refmarkup{#1}}{\label{#3}}\fi%
    \@esphack%
    \labelmarkup{#2}% visible printed text.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text. This is text. \labeltext{This is the labeled text with lab1}{lab1}. More text.\\
\labeltext[shorter text 2]{Long labeled text 2}{lab2}\\
\labeltext[HP]{homogeneity in preferences (HP)}{hyp3}

This reference shows lab1: \ref{lab1}.\\
This reference shows lab2: \ref{lab2}.\\
Reference to \ref{hyp3}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you’re using the ref-mechanism for something like acronyms so you might want consider using the `glossaries` package instead. That'll give you also the opportunity to automatically create a list of uses acronyms/abbreviations.

Here’s an example how to use the package to print the acronym: first time the full text and from there one only the abbreviation/acronym.

```
\documentclass[
   english,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{hp}{HP}{homogeneity in preferences}

\begin{document}

This is the first sentence about \gls{hp}.

Somewhere later in the doc it is used again as \gls{hp}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And by the way: Please **do not use** underlining!