# Beamer and `\hyperref`'s custom link text

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70143/cross-reference-with-custom-text), `hyperref` has the command `\hyperref[label]{text}` to insert internal links with custom text.

However, when using `beamer`, using `\hyperref` for that scenario always gives me links pointing to the first frame. How to circumvent this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Working reference: \ref{SomeLabel}
    
    \hyperref[SomeLabel]{Broken reference.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=SomeLabel]
    Target Frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I am using Beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57, Hyperref 2019/11/10 v7.00c.

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me: the link points to the target frame.

Comment: @Vincent I added version numbers for the packages used. I tried with different PDF viewers, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

In `beamer` do not use `label` for `hyperlinks`! Use `\hypertarget{label}{}` and time it with `\only<3->{}`. Don't forget to load `package` `hyperref`!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
\hypertarget{alma}{}
Kísértet járja be Európát – a kommunizmus kísértete. Szent hajszára szövetkezett e kísértet ellen a régi Európának minden hatalma: a pápa és a cár, Metternich és Guizot, francia radikálisok és német rendőrök.

Akad-e ellenzéki párt, amelyről kormányon levő ellenfelei nem híresztelték, hogy kommunista, akad-e ellenzéki párt, amelyik nem vágta vissza a kommunizmus megbélyegző vádját a haladottabb ellenzékieknek éppúgy, mint reakciós ellenfeleinek?

Ebből a tényből két dolog

A kommunizmust immár az összes európai hatalmak hatalomnak ismerik el.

Legfőbb ideje, hogy a kommunisták az egész világ előtt nyíltan kifejtsék nézeteiket, céljaikat, törekvéseiket, és a kommunizmus kísértetéről szóló mesékkel magának a pártnak a kiáltványát állítsák szembe.

Evégből a legkülönbözőbb nemzetiségű kommunisták összegyűltek Londonban, és papírra vetették a következő kiáltványt, amelyet angol, francia, német, olasz, flamand és dán nyelven tesznek közzé.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Thirdth}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Fourth}
\hyperlink{alma}{\beamerbutton{Jump to}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```