# Paraphrasing a section reference

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I am working on creating reference to help my document looks more fancy, however I would like paraphase the label and reference so that it wouldn't look ugly and terrible. Here below I give the information how should it look like.

The input :

```
\section{Problem No. 1}
"Problem sentences go here."
(\ref{Solution #1}{Solution}) %  <---- The code is just imaginary (I mean the desired code)
\section{Problem No. 2}
"Problem sentences go here."
(\ref{Solution #2}{Solution})
\section{Problem No. 1 - Solution}\label{Solution #1}
\section{Problem No. 2 - Solution}\label{Solution #2}
```

So that the desired output :

```
1. Problem No. 1
"Problem sentences go here."
(Solution) % <---- This refers to the Solution's section below the problem's section.
2. Problem No.2
"Problem sentences go here."
(Solution) % <---- Should refer to the "Problem No. 2 - Solution" section
3. Problem No. 1 - Solution
(Should refer to this section after clicking that hyperlink from Problem No. 1 section)
4. Problem No. 2 - Solution
(Should refer to this section after clicking that hyperlink from Problem No. 2 section)
```

Is there any possible method that I could use? (Perhaps also for equations, chapeters and numberings?)

Comment: Welcome! Did you compile your code twice?

Comment: I already did it, but the reference showing the name of the section. I mean based on that MWE, it shows like "Problem No. 1 - Solution", instead of "Solution"

Comment: How about [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70153/167081)?

Comment: Oh thanks, but how could I erase the box or the line, though?

Comment: When importing, use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116640/discussion-between-wilory-lu-and-m-al-jumaily).