# \ref with custom text

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using *`\ref`* to make cross references inside my article.

This works good but the text then will appear is like

> In the next chapter 1 we will [...]

But I want something like

> In the next chapter background we will [...]

Here an example of my usage

```
folgenden Kapitel \ref{mehrInformatiker} werden Maßnahmen
```

Will result in

[image: result]

I have read this article
[Cross-Reference with custom text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70143/cross-reference-with-custom-text)

But I would like to use `\ref`. Isn't it possible?

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: @Werner never used it, but if its easier then I will take a look at it.

Comment: The assumption is that `background` is the title of the chapter. It's not clear from your question, otherwise you'd just type `background` and don't need to use `\ref`. Correct? If so, [`nameref`](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref) is the package for your, and you can use `\nameref{<label>}`.

Comment: Yes i have lables I will try nameref thanks

Answer (score 5):

After I posted, cgnieder pointed out the existence of the `nameref` package, as in

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
I can even refer to section \nameref{s-1} before it is defined.

\section{Background so Long} \label{s-1}
I want to print just a number for Section \ref{s-1}.

But here, I want to print section \nameref{s-1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With it, `\nameref{<label>}` gives the *full* name of the section.  In this regard, what I had suggested is slightly different, in that the name one assigns to the textual reference may or may not be the same as the full section title.  Here was my original answer, edited to accentuate this difference:

I introduce optional arguments to `\label` to assign a textual reference (which, importantly, need not match the section name), and then use the newly defined `[s]` option to `\ref` to invoke the "special" textual reference rather than the usual [numerical] response.

By writing it to the `aux` file, I can invoke the textual reference before it is even defined.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\let\svlabel\label
\let\svref\ref
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\label[2][\relax]{%
  \svlabel{#2}%
  \ifx\relax#1\else
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string%
      \expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname custom#2\noexpand\endcsname{#1}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\ref[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx s#1\csname custom#2\endcsname\else\svref{#2}\fi
}
\begin{document}
I can even refer to section \ref[s]{s-1} before it is defined.

\section{Background so Long} \label[Background]{s-1}
I want to print just a number for Section \ref{s-1}.

But here, I want to print section \ref[s]{s-1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one only needed to reference "backwards", meaning after a label was defined, one can dispense with the aux file write to a simpler alternative:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\let\svlabel\label
\let\svref\ref
\renewcommand\label[2][\relax]{%
  \svlabel{#2}%
  \ifx\relax#1\else
      \expandafter\gdef\csname custom#2\endcsname{#1}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand\ref[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx s#1\csname custom#2\endcsname\else\svref{#2}\fi
}
\begin{document}
I cannot refer to section ``\ref[s]{s-1}'' before it is defined.

\section{Background so Long} \label[Background]{s-1}
I want to print just a number for Section \ref{s-1}.

But here, I want to print section \ref[s]{s-1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am LaTeX beginner and this sounds like advanced stuff, is there not an easier solution. I mean in contrast to your answer using the hyperef would be easier right?

Comment: @Aalexander If you will only be referencing "backwards", meaning refer to section "Background" only after section "Background" is already labeled, then the `\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname custom#2\noexpand\endcsname{#1}}` can be replaced with `\expandafter\gdef\csname custom#2\endcsname{#1}`.  Likewise, without using `\@mainaux`, the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be removed.

Comment: @Aalexander See my edit, in which I show the *simpler* version.

Comment: Have you just re-invented https://ctan.org/pkg/nameref?

Comment: @cgnieder I have no idea.  I've not used it.